# Inserting a variadic argument list into a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

Forgive me if this has been answered already, as I couldn't find it...

Basically I have an object that needs to take a variadic argument list in it's constructor and store the arguments in a vector. How do I initialize a vector from a the arguments of a variadic constructor?

```
class GenericNode {
public:
    GenericNode(GenericNode*... inputs) {
            /* Something like... */
        // inputs_.push_back(inputs)...;
}
private:
    std::vector<GenericNode*> inputs_;
};
```

Comment: There's some invalid syntax in your example.  What specifically are you trying to ask?

Comment: use `std::initializer_list<GenericNode*>`.

Comment: Sorry. To clarify, how do I use the argument list to populate a std::vector? @MooingDuck, i'll look into std::initializer_list. Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The *best* thing would be to use an initializer list

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
class GenericNode {
public:
    GenericNode(std::initializer_list<GenericNode*> inputs) 
        :inputs_(inputs) {} //well that's easy
private:
    std::vector<GenericNode*> inputs_;
};
int main() {
    GenericNode* ptr;
    GenericNode node{ptr, ptr, ptr, ptr};
} //compilation at http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=88ebac6a4490915fc4bc608765ba2b6c
```

The closest to what you already have, using C++11 is to use the vector's initializer_list:

```
    template<class ...Ts>
    GenericNode(Ts... inputs) 
        :inputs_{inputs...} {} //well that's easy too
    //compilation at http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2f7514b33401c51d33677bbff358f8ae
```

And here's a C++11 version with no initializer_lists at all.  It's ugly, and complicated, and requires features missing from many compilers.  Use the initializer list

```
template<class T>
using Alias = T;

class GenericNode {
public:
    template<class ...Ts>
    GenericNode(Ts... inputs) { //SFINAE might be appropriate
         using ptr = GenericNode*;
         Alias<char[]>{( //first part of magic unpacker
             inputs_.push_back(ptr(inputs))
             ,'0')...,'0'}; //second part of magic unpacker
    }
private:
    std::vector<GenericNode*> inputs_;
};
int main() {
    GenericNode* ptr;
    GenericNode node(ptr, ptr, ptr, ptr);
} //compilation at http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=57c533692166fb222adf5f837891e1f9
//thanks to R. Martinho Fernandes for helping me get it to compile
```

Unrelated to everything, I don't know if those are owning pointers or not.  If they are, use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't `template<typename... T> GenericNode(T*... inputs) :inputs_{ inputs... } { }` be closer to what he already has? i'd still go with `std::initializer_list<GenericNode*>` though.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: No idea why I never thought of that.  Fixed.

Comment: @MooingDuck, others: Thanks. Just what I needed.

Comment: Aside from the answer itself, and aside from wether it is practical or not, I find your 3rd solution very clever.  Is there a guide somewhere explaining the reason for the individual pieces?  Specifically, why the need for Alias, and why the need for the last '0' value?

Comment: @mmocny: I actually copy-pasted it from another answer I'd seen of another SO answer somewhere.  The alias is required to make a nameless temporary array, which makes it blatantly clear to any compiler that it doesn't actually need to make the array of chars.  For each `Ts` it adds a `'0'` to the array.  However, if you pass no inputs, that's the same as `char t[] = {}` which is invalid, so we tack on an extra `'0'` so there's always at least one element in the temporary array.

Comment: @TomášZato: Seems harsh. I answered the question completely, the reader can trivially figure out the includes themselves. Regardless: added.

Comment: Is the third solution guaranteed to preserve order?

Comment: @Zelta: Honestly, I can't recall. I sort of recall that the `...` is guaranteed to unpack in order, but I wouldn't swear it is so.

Comment: @MooingDuck if I remember correctly, it is guaranteed since c++17. So here's a better solution for c++ < 17: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33747281/3993308

Comment: And in c++17, there are fold expressions for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 10):

```
    // inputs_.push_back(inputs)...;
```

This doesn't work because you can't expand a parameter pack as a statement, only in certain contexts such as a function argument list or initializer-list.

Also your constructor signature is wrong, if you're trying to write a variadic template it needs to be a template!

Once you write your constructor signature correctly the answer is easy, just construct the vector with the pack expansion:

```
#include <vector>

class GenericNode
{
public:
  template<typename... T>
    GenericNode(T*... inputs) : inputs_{ inputs... }
    { }
private:
    std::vector<GenericNode*> inputs_;
};
```

(You could instead have set it in the constructor body with:

```
inputs_ = { inputs... };
```

but the cool kids use member initializers not assignment in the constructor body.)

The downside of this solution is that the template constructor accepts any type of pointer arguments, but will then give an error when trying to construct the vector if the arguments aren't convertible to `GenericNode*`.  You could constrain the template to only accept `GenericNode` pointers, but that's what happens automatically if you do what the other answers suggest and make the constructor take a `std::initializer_list<GenericNode*>`, and then you don't need any ugly `enable_if` SFINAE tricks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a variadic argument list unless it's a template, you can, as stated, use a initializer_list like this:

```
class GenericNode {
public:
    GenericNode(std::initializer_list<GenericNode*> inputs) : inputs_(inputs)
    {
    }
private:
    std::vector<GenericNode*> inputs_;
};

template <class ... T>
GenericNode* foo(T ... t)
{
    return new GenericNode({t...});
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the helper function?

Comment: @MooingDuck Just to show the use of variadic template parameters

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

template <typename T>
void variadic_vector_emplace(vector<T>&) {}

template <typename T, typename First, typename... Args>
void variadic_vector_emplace(vector<T>& v, First&& first, Args&&... args)
{
    v.emplace_back(std::forward<First>(first));
    variadic_vector_emplace(v, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct my_struct
{
    template <typename... Args>
    my_struct(Args&&... args)
    {
        variadic_vector_emplace(_data, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    vector<int>& data() { return _data; }

private:
  vector<int> _data;
};


int main()
{
    my_struct my(5, 6, 7, 8);

    for(int i : my.data())
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Blob
 {
    std::vector<std::string> _v;
 public:

    template<typename... Args>
    Blob(Args&&... args)
    : _v(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {  }

};

int main(void)
{
    const char * shapes[3] = { "Circle", "Triangle", "Square" };

    Blob b1(5, "C++ Truths"); 
    Blob b2(shapes, shapes+3);
}
```

Example from C++11 Truths looks simple enough...;)
Not a complete solution but might give you some ideas.

Comment: This works ok for your `b1` and `b2` examples, but the OP wants to do `Blob b3{ "Circle", "Triangle", "Square" };` and your `Blob` constructor can't do that, because you use value-initialization for `_v`. If you change it to use list-initialization for `_v` it would support what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

Note: If the element-type of a vector is not copy-initializable (it is in OP post), the std::initializer list route will not work.

You can still use a variadic unpack statement (post C++ 17):

```
(inputs_.emplace_back(std::move(args)), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote the following function that takes a string with
{1} , {2} , {3} ... in it and substitutes the argument list. I ran in to the same problem until I decided to let the compiler work it out for itself with the auto keyword.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

template<typename S, typename... Args>
string interpolate( const S& orig , const Args&... args)
{
   string out(orig);

   auto va = {args...};
   vector<string> v{va};

   size_t i = 1;

   for( string s: v)
    {
      string is = std::to_string(i);
      string t = "{" +  is + "}";
      try
         {
           auto pos = out.find(t);
           if(pos != out.npos) 
              {
                 out.erase(pos, t.length());
                 out.insert( pos, s); 
              }                  
           i++;
         }
    catch( std::exception& e)
       {
          std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
       }
     } // for

   return out;
 }
```

Apparently that is good enough as long as the types line up correctly.
In this case I am using only std::string throughout.
I think this is an elegant technique, but it may have drawbacks.