# Variadic construction for initialising vector of unique_ptr to base type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Below is an example program where a 'Container' class needs to store a list of 'Items' via a base class pointer. Having started with C++11/14 the natural choice would be to use std::unique_ptr and variadic templates in the case I have.

However being new I cannot fathom how to convert the variadic list into and initialiser list for the vector of unique_ptr in a manner that compiles. Help is greatly appreciated as I have failed to find anything online that helps me with this issue so far (albeit likely out there!).

Thanks in advance:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Item
{
};


struct Container
{
    template<typename... Items>
    Container( Items&&... items ) 
    : items_( {std::make_unique<Items>(items)...} ) //<<TODO: How, VC compiler times out with this code!?
    {
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items_;
};

struct A : Item { A(float){}  };
struct B : Item {  };
struct C : B    { C(float){} };
struct D : Item { D(float){} };

int main()
{
  Container x( A(1), C(2), D(3) );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot move `unique_ptr` out from `intializer_list`. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type) for more details.

This solution use the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469002/642626) that instead of using `intializer_list`, you can use plain array to construct items.

```
struct Container
{
    template<typename... Items>
    Container( Items&&... items ) 
    : items_()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Item> itemArr[] = {std::make_unique<Items>(std::move(items))...};
        items_ = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> {std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(itemArr)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(itemArr))};
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items_;
};
```

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15300adeb07fcea5)

Comment: I see how your solution works. Albeit needing the move  I gather from the links this is the cleanest answer. I will try it out later and accept I expect

Comment: I have just been using this finally, I have made  minor edit as in use it became apparent that the items were being copied with std:::make_ptr instead. I can't explain how std::move makes it work but this looks to be a fix.