# converting parameter pack into a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to understand variadic templates in C++ and I am lost in the following example: Imagine a function **foo(T, T, T, T)** which takes variadic number of arguments of the same type T and converts them into a vector. Any idea how to implement one?

It should work like this

```
foo<int>(1,2,3,4) returns std::vector<int> x{1,2,3,4}
foo<double>(0.1,0.2,0.3) returns std::vector<double> x{0.1,0.2,0.3}
```

Comment: You forgot to include a question in your post.

Comment: do you mean `std::vector<T> x { { IS... } };` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978916/inserting-a-variadic-argument-list-into-a-vector

Comment: `Is` is the parameter pack but you're trying to expand `i`. Is that the problem you're having or is it something else? Might want to try clarifying exactly what you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 9):

If the `T` values as known at compile-time, you can pass they as template parameters and write something like

```
template<typename T, T ... Is>
void foo() {
   std::vector<T> x { { Is.. } };

   for( auto xx:x )
      std::cout << xx << std::endl;
}
```

that is called

```
foo<int, 2, 3, 5, 7>();
```

Otherwise you have to pass they as arguments; something like

```
template <typename T, typename ... ARGS>
void foo (ARGS const & ... args) {    
   std::vector<T> x { { args... } };

   for( auto xx:x ) 
      std::cout << xx << std::endl;
}
```

that is called

```
foo<int>(2, 3, 5, 7);
```

or also (deducing the type `T` from the first argument)

```
template <typename T, typename ... ARGS>
void foo (T const & arg0, ARGS const & ... args) {    
   std::vector<T> x { { arg0, args... } };

   for( auto xx:x ) 
      std::cout << xx << std::endl;
}
```

that is called

```
foo(2, 3, 5, 7);
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP write

> It should work like this

```
foo<int>(1,2,3,4) returns std::vector<int> x{1,2,3,4}
foo<double>(0.1,0.2,0.3) returns std::vector<double> x{0.1,0.2,0.3}
```

So I suppose you can simply write

```
template <typename T, typename ... ARGS>
std::vector<T> foo (ARGS const & ... args)
 { return { args... }; }
```

Comment: You can also skip the vector entirely: `for (auto x: { Is... })`

Answer (score 0):

In foo, I create a vector with the exact capacity to hold all the parameters and then recursively handle each parameter by pushing it to the back of the vector, which is passed to a helper template function called append_to_vector.

```
#include<vector>    
namespace test2
{
    template<typename TN>
    void append_to_vector(std::vector<TN>& outputvector, const TN& elem)
    {
        outputvector.push_back(elem);
    };

    template<typename T0, typename ...T1toN>
    void append_to_vector(std::vector<T0>& outputvector, const T0& elem, T1toN... elems)
    {
        outputvector.push_back(elem);
        append_to_vector(outputvector, elems...);
    };

    template<typename T, typename ...T0toN>
    auto foo(const T0toN... elems)
    {
        std::vector<T> vec;
        vec.reserve(sizeof...(elems));
        append_to_vector(vec, elems...);
        return vec;
    };
}



int main()
{
   std::vector<int> vec;
   auto vec1 = test2::foo<int>(1,2,3,4);
   auto vec2 = test2::foo<double>(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Way to do it in C++14:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> function(std::initializer_list<T> elements)
{
    return std::vector<T>(elements.begin(), elements.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> elements = function<int>({1, 2, 3});
    std::copy(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::ostream_iterator<const int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```