# C++14 Create vector from variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Suppose, I have a structure

```
struct A
{
   std::string name;
};
```

and want to write function which reads field "name" from objects and return them 
as `std::vector<std::string>`.
Is it possible to do this by variadic templates (or any non-iterative method).
My goal is something like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::vector<std::string> function(Ts... ts)
{
    ...
}
```

in program:

```
    A a1, a2, a3, a4;
    function(a1, a2, a3, a4);
```

output: `{a1.name, a2.name, a3.name, a4.name}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A really simple expansion that works in C++11:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::vector<std::string> function(Ts&& ... ts)
{
    return {std::forward<Ts>(ts).name...};
}
```

(forwarding references not required)

What happens is, that the vector is constructed with [initializer list, constructed from the variadic parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126273/converting-parameter-pack-into-a-vector), while [applying a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848910/apply-function-on-each-element-in-parameter-pack) (member access operator) for each variadic element.

Comment: Does the perfect forwarding work here? In case of `function(std::move(a1));`, `a1` will be treated as rvalue, but it's `name` member variable will be an lvalue. Or, will not?

Comment: Sorry, just found out that the member variable will be rvalue as well (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609226/580083). Didn't know this rule.

Comment: @DanielLangr To be honest, you made me doubtful, so thanks for the link.