# How to convert variadic in the vector to it was a holder of arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13979720/3253896). It works but I want to my class was owner of arguments. I have the next code:

```
template <class val_t>
class exp_t {
public:
    exp_t() {}
    virtual ~exp_t() {}

    virtual bool is(const std::vector<val_t> &kb) const = 0;
};

template <class val_t>
class fact_t: exp_t<val_t> {
public:
    const val_t m_value;

    fact_t(const val_t value): m_value{value} {}

    virtual bool is(const std::vector<val_t> &kb) const {
        return std::find(kb.begin(), kb.end(), m_value) != kb.end();
    }
};

template <class val_t>
class not_t: public exp_t<val_t> {
    exp_t<val_t> m_exp;
public:
    not_t(exp_t<val_t> exp): exp_t<val_t>(), m_exp{exp} {}

    virtual bool is(const std::vector<val_t> &kb) const override {
        return !m_exp.is(kb);
    }
};

template <class val_t, class ... args_t>
class and_t: public exp_t<val_t> {
    std::vector<exp_t<val_t>> m_exps;
public:
    and_t(args_t... exps) : exp_t<val_t>(), m_exps{{exps...}} {}

    virtual bool is(const std::vector<val_t> &kb) const override {
        for (auto &exp : m_exps) {
            if (!exp.is(kb)) { return false; }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

I need to I could write a something like below:

```
exp_t<int> *get_exp() {  
    return new and_t<int>(fact_t<int>(5), fact_t<int>(6));
}
```

I.e. to I could return my `exp_t` and it saved passed arguments (for example using move semantic, I know how to make classes movable, but I don't know how to rewrite `and_t` constructor to pass it and convert to the `std::vector`).
How can I change my class `and_t`? Is it possible in C++?

**P.S.** I tried to get by myself reading about variadics but I understood a nothing just.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I.e. to I could return my exp_t and it saved passed arguments (for example using move semantic, I know how to make classes movable, but I don't know how to rewrite and_t constructor to pass it and convert to the std::vector)

If you know (if you are **sure**) that all arguments are r-values, you can use move semantics as follows

```
 and_t (args_t && ... exps)
    : exp_t<val_t>(), m_exps{{std::move(exps)...}}
  { }
```

Otherwise (if some arguments can be r-values, some l-values), you can use perfect forwarding

```
template <typename ... Args>
and_t (Args && ... exps)
   : exp_t<val_t>(), m_exps{{std::forward<Args>(exps)...}}
 { }
```

So you move r-values and copy l-values.

I suppose the best way is the second one (perfect forwarding) so there is no need of `args_t` variadic list of types for `and_t` class.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll rewrite my class with `std::forward`.